# How to make word-break: break-all work in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, textarea

I have a textarea like this:

```css
textarea {
  background: lightgray;
  border: none;
  font: 16px/16px Courier;
  resize: none;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<textarea cols="40" rows="10 wrap="hard">
[[Lorem]][[ipsum]][[dolor]][[sit]][[amet]][[consectetur]][[adipiscing]][[elit]][[sed]][[do]][[eiusmod]][[tempor]][[incididunt]][[ut]][[labore]][[et]][[dolore]][[magna]][[aliqua]][[Ut]][[enim]][[ad]][[minim]][[veniam]][[quis]][[nostrud]][[exercitation]][[ullamco]][[laboris]][[nisi]][[ut]][[aliquip]][[ex]][[ea]][[commodo]][[consequat]][[Duis]][[aute]][[irure]][[dolor]][[in]][[reprehenderit]][[in]][[voluptate]][[velit]][[esse]][[cillum]][[dolore]][[eu]][[fugiat]][[nulla]][[pariatur]][[Excepteur]][[sint]][[occaecat]][[cupidatat]][[non]][[proident]][[sunt]][[in]][[culpa]][[qui]][[officia]][[deserunt]][[mollit]][[anim]][[id]][[est]][[laborum]]
</textarea>
```

In Firefox, I see this: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5YL7.png)

But in Chrome, the line breaks are garbled: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gpj5Y.png)

How can I tell Chrome to break a line after exactly 40 characters and not less or more, the same way as Firefox is doing?

Answer (score 1):

Use `hyphens` and `word-break` with other toolkit together. I hope this might help you.

```css
textarea {
  background: lightgray;
  border: none;
  font: 16px/16px Courier;
  resize: none;

   word-break: break-all;
  -ms-word-break: break-all;
   word-break: break-all;   
  
 word-break: break-word; /* Non standard for WebKit */
 -webkit-hyphens: auto;
   -moz-hyphens: auto;
        hyphens: auto;
}
```

```html
<textarea cols="40" rows="10 wrap="hard">
[[Lorem]][[ipsum]][[dolor]][[sit]][[amet]][[consectetur]][[adipiscing]][[elit]][[sed]][[do]][[eiusmod]][[tempor]][[incididunt]][[ut]][[labore]][[et]][[dolore]][[magna]][[aliqua]][[Ut]][[enim]][[ad]][[minim]][[veniam]][[quis]][[nostrud]][[exercitation]][[ullamco]][[laboris]][[nisi]][[ut]][[aliquip]][[ex]][[ea]][[commodo]][[consequat]][[Duis]][[aute]][[irure]][[dolor]][[in]][[reprehenderit]][[in]][[voluptate]][[velit]][[esse]][[cillum]][[dolore]][[eu]][[fugiat]][[nulla]][[pariatur]][[Excepteur]][[sint]][[occaecat]][[cupidatat]][[non]][[proident]][[sunt]][[in]][[culpa]][[qui]][[officia]][[deserunt]][[mollit]][[anim]][[id]][[est]][[laborum]]
</textarea>
```

Comment: sorry, still broken.